# Getting video from onboard to remote computer

Tags: dji-sdk, manifold

I am trying to get zenmuse x3 mounted on M100 video feed to a remote computer through SSH from onboard computer. I tried to add remote computer IP to sshd_conf file but It is giving "can't open display" issue. Anybody tried to do the same? Please give suggestions to achieve this objective.
the onboard and remote computer on the same network
Thank you,
Pavan

Comment: have you checked : https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

Comment: Thank you! I will check it.